Снова о Макрос CheckBox
Я уже обращался по поводу этого Макроса (Макрос Checkbox)-получил исчерпывающий ответ:
For i = 1 To 6
  If Controls("CheckBox" & i) = False Then  
    MsgBox "TEST", vbOKOnly
  End If
Next

Но мой Excel на отрез не хочет его запускать, VBA-редактор сообщает что
Controls not defined
Прошу помочь разобраться. Продолжая поиски на свой вопрос выяснил, что есть ответ, на этом же англоязычном сайте https://stackoverflow.com/a/57983985/27667238,данный еще в 2019 г, но мой уровень английского не позволил сразу найти ответ.

А где находится этот код? Он будет работать только на форме.

В модуле эта книга. Мне не нужно создавать форму

А к чему тогда это относится "CheckBox" & i? Это чекбокс на рабочем листе?

При открытие книги проверяет CheckBox  если неактивен выдает Тест. У меня сейчас работает
  If ActiveSheet.CheckBox1 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox2 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox3 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox4 _
  Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox5 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox6 = False Then 
    MsgBox "TEST", vbOKOnly
 End If


А сразу нельзя было написать?

Вот код     Public Sub Workbook_Open()
mnName = MonthName(Month(Now))
Add_New_Sheet
Worksheets(mnName).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = Now
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Select
If ActiveSheet.CheckBox1 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox2 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox3 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox4 _
Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox5 Or ActiveSheet.CheckBox6 = False Then
MsgBox "TEST", vbOKOnly
End If

А сразу нельзя было спросить?

Мы тут не должны вытягивать из вас всю информацию.Чем полнее будет ваш вопрос, тем быстрее вы получите более точный ответ. Тем не менее, ответ касательно чекбокса на рабочем листе я предоставил.

Доступ к объектам на рабочем листе осуществляется через коллекцию Shapes:

Для Form Controls:

ActiveSeet.Shapes("CheckBox" & i).DrawingObject


Для ActiveX Controls:

ActiveSeet.Shapes("CheckBox" & i).DrawingObject.Object

Определить тип чекбокса можно по внешнему виду, поведению или по значению Shape.Type: ActiveSeet.Shapes("CheckBox" & i).Type

msoFormControl - это чекбокс типа Form Control.
msoOLEControlObject - это чекбокс типа ActiveX Control.


@Леонид, 0) Отредактируйте вопрос: добавьте в него ссылку на предыдущий, где был предоставлен ответ; 1) Примите текущий  ответ, если он помог; 2) Напоминаю вам: Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?

Что-то непонятно в ответе?

Если Вы напомните вторую учетную запись я выполню требование объеденнить их.

Это не требование, можете игнорировать, так как в другой учётной записи у вас ничего нет.

@Леонид, действительно, rotabor прав, это не требование, а просьба — право остаётся за вами. Просто мне кажется, вам же будет удобнее иметь 2 вопроса в одной учётной записи. Вот ваша вторая учётная запись

пока еще не разобрался с необычной организацией сайта, к примеру как получается у одних драдиционные публикации кодов у меня в одну строку потом кто-то их , благадарю за это, поправляет. Может чего то в свои 75 не дагоняю

Под вопросом есть ссылка "Править". Кликните и посмотрите, как оформлен код. А в заголовке блока для правки текста справа есть значок со знаком вопроса. Если кликните, то узнаете все остальные хитрости оформления вопросов и ответов. Удачи!
